# Criando arquivo texto com stream

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-code

Eu sou iniciante e no momento estou estudando sobre manipulação de arquivos, então fui testar criar um arquivo texto com stream que eu vi de uma aula em um bootcamp que estou participando, mas tá dando erro. Eu fui testar o código como o professor ensinou e não sei o que está acontecendo, se eu passei desapercebido em algum detalhe... ou se é a versão do .net (estou usando 6.0), enfim, poderiam me ajudar? c# e .Net6.0

'''
public class Filehelper
{
public void CriarArquivoTextoStream(string caminho, List conteudo)
{
using (var stream = File.CreateText(caminho));
{
foreach (var linha in conteudo)
{
stream.WriteLine(linha);
}
}
}
}'''
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

''' class Program
{
static void Main(string[] args)

```
{   
    var caminho = "C:/Users/anaju/DIO/Workingwithfiles";
    var caminhoPathCombine = Path.Combine(caminho,"test1");
    var caminhoArquivo = Path.Combine(caminho, "arquivo-teste-stream.txt");
    var listaString = new List<string> ( "linha 1", "linha 2", "linha 3" );

    Filehelper helper = new Filehelper();
    helper.CriarArquivoTextoStream(caminhoArquivo, listaString); '''
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Boas-vindas ao site. É importante **[edit], remover o código complexo e no lugar adicionar um [mcve] (NÃO delete e NÃO repita a pergunta)** ([NÃO use imagens para mostrar códigos e logs](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/7817/3635)), com um passo a passo do que já fez e explicar de forma clara e objetiva e então aguarde o processo de reabertura (que será avaliado por outros usuários). Para aproveitar melhor o site, entender e evitar fechamentos vale a pena ler o [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045). Obrigado por compreender.

Answer (score 1):

De acordo com cada mensagem de erro que recebeu:

> Type 'Filehelper' already defines a member called...

[Referência do erro CS0111](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0111).

Esse erro foi exibido porque você já tem um método de mesmo nome que recebe os mesmos parâmetros. Caso você queira criar um método de mesmo nome mas com parâmetros diferentes, você quer uma [sobrecarga](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobrecarga_de_fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o). Troque a quantidade de parâmetros e/ou seus tipos para ter uma função chamada de forma diferente, mas de mesmo nome.

> The name 'stream' does not exist in the current context

Você está referenciando uma variável que não havia sido declarada ("criada") antes, exemplo:

```
arquivo.WriteAsync(...
```

Sem ter feito isso antes:

```
var arquivo = File...
```

A variável não existia até chamarmos o `WriteAsync`.

[Referência do erro CS0103](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs0103).

> 'List' does not contain a constructor that takes 3 arguments

Você quis criar uma lista com três itens usando o construtor da classe `List<T>`, mas ele não tem um sobrecarga que receba 3 argumentos. O que você quer é usar a inicialização de itens para criar uma lista com N valores, ou seja, inicializar os valores ao criar o objeto; como no exemplo:

```
new List<string> { "primeiro", "segundo", "terceiro" };
```

Perceba que estamos usando *chaves* e não *parênteses*.

[Referência do erro CS1729](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs1729).

> The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties

O compilador não consegue distinguir entre métodos conhecidos com o mesmo nome, dado que suas chamadas não são tão diferentes a ponto de conseguir fazer essa distinção. Exemplo:

Caso tenhamos dois métodos chamados `LeArquivo`, vindos de uma classe de mesmo nome `GerenciaArquivo` mas de namespaces diferentes, o compilador não vai conseguir distinguir qual é o método que desejamos chamar. Nesse caso, teríamos que colocar o namespace na chamada, dizendo ao compilador que aquele é o método que desejamos:

```
[Nome do namespace].GerenciaArquivo.LeArquivo();
```

Ao invés da forma em que não é possível distinguir entre os dois:

```
GerenciaArquivo.LeArquivo();
```

[Referência do erro CS0121](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0121).

Lembrando que é recomendado evitar criar métodos de mesmo nome e/ou classes com mesmo nome e namespaces diferentes, pois isso dificulta muito a manutenção com o tempo. O ideal é que você *quase nunca* se depare com esse erro. Isso também se aplica a criar métodos com o mesmo nome de métodos da linguagem, como criar uma classe `Console` com um método estático `WriteLine` que recebe os mesmos parâmetros.